# Is it possible with imagemagick-convert to dynamically calculate a rotation angle while processing images?

Tags: image, image-processing, imagemagick, image-manipulation, imagemagick-convert

I'd like to place a watermark diagonally over a number of images. Since the dimensions of these images vary, but the watermark should always have the maximal possible size at constant proportions, I have to calculate the perfect angle for the resizing. (It should look like [that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfc4R.jpg). Not like [that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ok16l.jpg).)

I use the following algorithm:

```
ratio1 = pic1_width / pic1_height
ratio2 = pic2_width / pic2_height
angle = atan ((ratio1 - ratio2) / (1 - ratio1 * ratio2))
```

For a detailed explanation see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48399194/how-to-calculate-the-rotation-angle-for-an-overlying-image-so-that-it-just-fits).

**Is there any way to do this calculation dynamically during image processing?**

I'm using ImageMagick 6.8.9-9 Q16 x86_64 on Ubuntu Linux.
In Bash it might look something like this (without the resizing):

```
convert -background none -gravity center -density 300 "$pic" \
    \( "$wmark" -rotate "%[fx:atan(((u.w/u.h)-(v.w/v.h))/(1-(u.w/u.h)*(v.w/v.h)))]" \) \
    -compose over -composite "$result"
```

The code does not rotate the image. I think that's because "-rotate" does not accept "%[fx:]" arguments? Unfortunately, I have not been able to find clear information about this so far ...
In addition, the variables "w" and "h" seem to have the value "0" ... which I also do not understand.

Best regards
AFoeee

Comment: You need to upgrade to v7 of ImageMagick to get the capability to do replacement in the `-rotate` parameter. You'd also need to use `magick -background ...` rather than `convert -background ...`

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Meanwhile, I switched to IM7. A solution to my problem can be found under [this thread](https://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=33423&p=153475#p153466) in the ImageMagick forum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the sake of completeness, here is the solution that was created with help from [the ImageMagick Community](https://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=33423):

```
wmark="watermark.png"
file="some.pdf"
result="result.jpg"

rotation="%[fx:ratioUF=u.w/u.h; ratioWM=v.w/v.h; t*(atan((ratioUF-ratioWM)/(1-ratioUF*ratioWM))*180/Pi)]"

magick  -define registry:temporary-path=/tmp/imagemagick \
        -background none \
        -density 300 \
        "$file" \
        -bordercolor none -border 1x1 -trim +repage \
        "$wmark" \
        -rotate "$rotation" \
        -resize "%[fx:u.w]x%[fx:u.h]" \
        -compose over -gravity center -composite \
        -background white \
        -flatten \
        "$result"
```

This approach requires IM7.

Best regards
AFoeee

Comment: This will work in both IM 6 convert  and IM 7 magick, if you replace -rotate with +distort SRT. In IM 6, only a few operations allow inline computations, one of which is distort. See http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/distorts/#srt. You can also include the resize in the +distort SRT as one operation including both rotation and scaling.